# Wifi not showing in Live usb boot

Tags: wireless, live-usb

Hope you are doing well.

I have live booted Ubuntu 22.04. Lts, on my pc which has Windows 10. just to check how Ubuntu works and test it out. I want to find a different OS that is close to Windows 10 but free.

But when I wanted to connect to wifi i saw that there was no place to connect to a wifi only through cable. I don't have a cable compatible wifi.

My Pc is an ASUS but I have no Idea what model it is, i am not a pc expert it was build so it doesn't show any information on the case, only at start up shows ASus, the Wifi is also a big flat  black Aerial.  That has 2 nuts that can screw in at the back of the PC.

I hope that this information is enough to help.
I would greatly appreciate help on why this is? And if it can be easily fixed or should I use a different Linux system?

Would appreciate help.
Have a great evening.
Kind regards
Johan

Ps. I have checked search wifi and it just said that wifi isn't available if i remember correctly. I can't find any information on this particular problem. I was wondering if Live USB boot make a difference if wifi is available or not because it is not installed on the pc?

Comment: There are three possibilities. First, you have a device driver but it isn't working properly. Second, you have a driver that requires but can't find firmware. Or, third, there is no in-kernel driver and you'd need to install one manually. We don't know which to suspect without more details. Please open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+t) and run: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and: `lsusb` Next, please edit your question to show the results.